# Custom Overlay for Mapkit using swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I can't for the life of me get a line drawn between two points when subclassing an `MKOverlay` and attempting it in the `draw(_mapRect..` method.

The reason I am doing the subclass instead of a polyline is that I will need to add some additional items later (images, etc). So it was decided to subclass out.

However for a simple proof of concept I can images, but not any lines. Below is a basic example of this and I'm sure it's something I am not including.  I've verified this delegate is always hit after `mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay)` is called in the controller.  Any insight would really help.

```
override func draw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext) {
    var coordinate1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.204082,-86.660156);
    var coordinate2 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.762030,-100.019531);

    var p1 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate1)

    var p2 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate2)

    context.saveGState()
    let green = UIColor.green

    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)

    context.setLineWidth(800.0)

    context.beginPath()

    let point1 = self.point(for: p1)
    let point2 = self.point(for: p2)

    context.move(to: point1)
    context.addLine(to: point2)
    context.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
    context.restoreGState()
}
```

Comment: but where are you adding this custom polyline to your mapView?

Comment: For demo purposes I was just adding it in viewDidAppear(_:).

Comment: can you post all the relevant code in order to try help you?